# There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: false. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to resolve this error. I have implemented a custom drop down and it generate this error

```html
 
 DropDownWidget(
                          list: ["Patient","HouseholdMember","Communityrepresentative","Other"],
                          data: whofollowUp,
                          hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
                          heading: getTranslated(context, "followup_patient"),
                        ),
```

the custom drop down that is generating this error and I don't have the option to use the default one that comes with flutter

```html
class DropDownWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<dynamic> data;
  final String heading;
  final List<String> list;
  final String hint;
  final bool showPadding;
  final Color outlineColor;
  final Function onChange;
  final bool isDecode;


  DropDownWidget(
      {Key key,
      this.data,
      this.heading,
      this.list,
      this.outlineColor = const Color(0xffC4C4C4),
      this.hint,
      this.onChange,
      this.isDecode = false,
      this.showPadding = true})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, left: 8),
          child: Text(
            heading,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColor.primarypurple,
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 40,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          width: ResponsiveSize.sizeWidth(context),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColor.backGrey,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              border: Border.all(width: 2, color: AppColor.darkBlue)),
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: data,
            builder: (ctx, value, child) => DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: list.map((var val) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      value:
                          isDecode ? ((jsonDecode(val))["id"]).toString() : val,
                      child: new Text(
                       isDecode ?  ((jsonDecode(val))["name"]).toString(): val,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  // hint: Text(
                  //   hint,
                  //   maxLines: 1,
                  //   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  //   style: TextStyle(
                  //       fontSize: 14,
                  //       color: AppColor.darkBlue,
                  //       fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  // ),
                  value: value,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    color: AppColor.darkBlue,
                  ),
                  onChanged: onChange == null
                      ? (newVal) {
                          data.value = newVal;
                        }
                      : (newVal) {
                          data.value = newVal;
                          onChange();
                        }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is a custom drop down which I am trying to use it in my class and it is giving this error which I am unable  to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a repetitive (or no matched) value for your dropdown items. One of these 4 solutions would be helpful (check them as follow):

1. recheck and be sure that your elements' id does not be equal here:

```
value:isDecode ? ((jsonDecode(val))["id"]).toString() :val,
```

2. maybe `isDecode` is false and you have a REPETITIVE element in your list!
3. finally, the last possibility can be the value of the `value` parameter. In the  other words maybe it does not match with any item's value:

```
value: value,
```

check it out and let me know the result.